# Take sum of items in Foreach loop in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have a list and I want to display Sum of one of the properties.

I tried this, but it is not adding value, but it is working as string Concat.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Details)
{
    int a = 0;
    a += Convert.ToInt32(item.Amt);
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => a)
                                                
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave only addition in the loop. Take the rest of the code out of the loop.

```
@{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model.Details)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Amt);
    }
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => sum)
}
```

Also you can use LINQ.

```
@{
    var sum = Model.Details.Sum(x => x.Amt);
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make it shorter this way

```
<h1>@Model.Details.Sum(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.Amt))</h1>
```